# Is there a way to generate a ctags file for the php 7 library on CentOS 7 and include it in a project?

Tags: php, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Within a project I can generate a ctags file with ctag -R . and then use Ctrl-] to go to the source of a function.  I would like to do the same with the native php functions (ie. is_array(), foreach(), etc).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using <kbd>K</kbd>? It will run an external command using the keyword under the cursor. By default it runs `man`, but that program can be defined in `'keywordprg'` option.

It appears there's already a wiki entry for using this flow in PHP [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PHP_online_help).

Comment: I think this answer is good.  I followed the instructions on [link](http://bjori.blogspot.com/2010/01/unix-manual-pages-for-php-functions.html) which is pretty much what you describe here.